# Can a solidity event be logged successfully before a throw?

Tags: solidity, events

If I have the following code in a solidity contract function:

```
event_logEvent();
throw;
```

Does the event get logged correctly into the blockchain or does the throw also revert all the events?

Comment: Upvoted, but think this is a duplicate.  (Will clean up this comment soon.)